# How can I read the sourcecode of a PDF

Tags: pdf

I want get the sourcecode of a PDF File. Unfortunately once I open the PDF with a texteditor some lines doesn't make sense... just like....

```
%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
3 0 obj
<</Ff 0/F 6/Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/DR<</Font<</Helv 2 0 R>>>>/T(Ä\n¬4^XÈ4ýæçO§W²W^D³^Ywzº<92>õÌ^AÀÄi]â<96><8c>)/V(Ä\n¬4^XÈ4ýæçO§W²W^Dø<93>r^D¥à<82>ú<83>Z^Q7^Cv^FÈ)/AP<</N 1 0 R>>/P 4 0 R/BS<</W 1/S/S>>/FT/Tx/Rect[40 50 70 80]/DA(Ä\n¬4^XÈ4ýæçO§W²W^Dù~êw3<84>&^X´âL|q@³^VC<8a>"Ýo^N¿=Ì<91>ta^R`àz)>>
endobj
6 0 obj
```

so %PDF-1.6 is fine but after it s not resolving the correct letters.... I tried with vim ... is there any chance to get the correct content ....

Comment: I don't believe you can unbuild a PDF to have to source code back. Altough if you want to do some small editing over an existing on you can try pdfedit or pdf-Xchange viewer over wine.

Comment: thx... the reason why I am asking is... that I try to get forms like circles,lines and so on out of a PDF with Java (I actually just want to know their position + size)... unfortunately libraries like Itext won't retrieve this info... so I try to write my own lib... but I need to see the whole original code of a PDF to get the idea behind .... PDFedit helped a bit but I really want to see the whole Code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't open the PDF file with a regular text editor, you have to use a Hex Editor, like ghex. Install it by running on console:

```
sudo apt-get install ghex
```

Or look for ghex into Ubuntu Software Center.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try qpdf:

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable orig.pdf expanded.pdf
```

You should be able to open 'expanded.pdf' in a text editor.

(You'll probably have to install qpdf, naturally.)